# Are all alkene geometrical isomers achiral?

Tags: stereochemistry

I was reading a book and it tells that alkene geometrical isomers are achiral.
I wanted to know that is it applicable for alkene geometrical isomers?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want a rule which is not there. Alkenes, like nearly all other classes of organic compounds, may or may not be chiral. Let's put it this way: having a double bond is _irrelevant_ to chirality.

Comment: The statement in your book is a *truism*: Correct, but does not transport any additional insight into the underlying concepts. Except as an exercise question: *Why* do these isomers not show a stereoisomery?

Comment: @Karl Sadly, that statement isn't true. See my answer below...

Comment: @Zhe I would say that calling a cumulated diene an alkene is also a truism: Correct, but not at all helpful. ;-) *If* it is correct. Because the central carbon atom is *sp* hybridised.

Comment: Such questions always remind me of this one, no offence intended: https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: @Karl I forgot about that one :)

Answer (score 6):

While in general, you should consider chirality and alkene geometry as orthogonal concepts, the statement in your question isn't even true.

Consider the case of 2,3-pentadiene, aka, 1,3-dimethylallene. This compound is chiral. Any change in the geometry of either of the double bonds provides the other enantiomer.

[image: 2,3-pentadiene]